# Split text into two sentences in C#

Tags: c#

I want to divide a text into sentences.the sentence contains whitespace characters

For example:

```
Orginal sentence: 100 10 20 13
the result:
first sentence:100 10 20
second sentence:13
```

I tried split but the result was :

```
first:100
second:10
third:20
fourth:13
```

How can I do that?

Comment: What are the conditions for splitting into two sentences - a.k.a where do you break the sentence up?

Comment: Please be clearer about what the input is, and what the expected output is. If you could provide three to four examples that would be awesome.

Comment: Use `.Split()` and then use `.Join()` to re-combine the first three?  Use `.Substring()` on the specific index?  There's a variety of string manipulation methods on the `String` class, but what is the actual logic you want to implement for splitting the string?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You want all before the last space and the rest? You can use `String.LastIndexOf` and `Substring`:

```
string text = "100 10 20 13";
string firstPart = text;
string lastPart;

int lastSpaceIndex =  text.LastIndexOf(' ');
if(lastSpaceIndex >= 0)
{
    firstPart = text.Substring(0, lastSpaceIndex);
    lastPart = text.Substring(lastSpaceIndex).TrimStart();
}
```

Comment: What makes you think that it's always the last space that divides sentences? This may be a solution for the specific example, but chances are that the OP will not be happy with this solution.

Comment: @HelmutD Nothing better to do than complain at answers on a question that doesn't clearly ask what it wants? -edit- It does ask what it wants, you're just nagging

Comment: @HelmutD: i try to answer specifc questions that were asked. Even if OP hasn't mentioned it explicitly it's obvious that the first part contains all tokens but the last and the second part contains only the last. If he needs to cover other cases he should really mention it. While LINQ is always an option it's not necessary in this case. String methods are more efficient and the code is still readable.

Comment: @EpicKip "It does ask what it wants..." - How do you know what the OP wants, can you read his mind? Right now he might try out the proposed solutions on a five-word string - and probably find out that it doesn't do what he needs - instead of clarifying his requirement, and we all will have wasted our time.

Comment: @HelmutD you are the only one wasting time, we are trying to help out. Maybe answer some questions instead of just finding petty faults in other peoples?

Comment: @HelmutD op said I have A, I want B but I get C and at the end > `"How can I do that?" (get B)`. So yeah he said what he wants, now quit whining.

Comment: @EpicKip - Sorry, I didn't mean to offend you.

Comment: @HelmutD Don't even think you have the power to offend me. You're just some guy on the internet bothering people

Answer (score 3):

You can use Linq for this;

```
// This splits on white space
var split = original.Split(' ');

// This takes all split parts except for the last one
var first = split.Take(split.Count() - 1);
// And rejoins it
first = String.Join(" ", first);

// This gets the last one 
var last = split.Last();
```

Note: This is assuming that you want the first result to be every word except for the last and the second result to be only the last... If you have different requirements please clarify your question

Comment: This solution is problably too specific ;)

Comment: @HelmutD what do you mean too specific? I answered the exact question he asked...

Comment: Because you choose quite an arbitrary criterion for spitting words into sentences. You could as well build the first sentence from the first three words and the second from the rest, but I think neither solution is what the OP looks for.

Comment: @HelmutD Then OP has to specify, this generates the expected output in what I consider clean code.

Comment: @Milney - I still cannot see where he specified that he wants the string spilt before the last word as opposed to, say, after three words. But anyway, I see the OP has accepted on of the answers, so I apologise, and acknowledge that you're better at deducing the requirement from a specific example than I am.

Comment: @HelmutD you would hope that as a developer he can apply the logic used in these two answers to differing conditions, and was possibly just not aware which approach to take. The answer is not saying 'Use this exact code' but here is a way to try to tackle the problem